# Python: Missing Parts When Converting Text File Into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text

I am so new to programming and Stack Overflow. I have a text file as follows:

```
  -2807.557   127583628.769  99415830.714  95273508.861  24278349.326
  -1154.563   109739935.967  85511647.328  81948692.208  20882802.837
   1120.689   116602649.396  90859192.858  87073411.233  22188740.266
              124847113.835  97283456.793                23757610.353
   1197.150   110618019.067  86195868.474  82604380.229  21049905.359
              125883903.195  98091335.810                23954905.537
```

There are missing parts in my text file. I need to check them and insert 0. For example i want to create a dummy dataframe for index 0 like this:

```
  Sats:     Values:
    A     -2807.557

    B     -1154.563

    C      1120.689

    D      0

    E      1197.150 

    F      0
```

But on my output, row D and F shows next values instead of empty parts :

```
  Sats:     Values:
    A     -2807.557

    B     -1154.563

    C      1120.689

    D      124847113.835

    E      1197.150 

    F      125883903.195
```

Is there an algorithm to check missing parts in a row and insert 0 right there for every case like this?

Comment: How are you creating your DataFrame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read in your file using `pd.read_fwf()` and then use `fillna()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('test.txt', header=None)

df[0].fillna(0)
```

Yields:

```
0   -2807.557
1   -1154.563
2    1120.689
3       0.000
4    1197.150
5       0.000
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```